# Change connection name for multiple databases

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, database-migration

I am using two different databases for my rails app. I connect my user model to a second database by adding the line below into user.rb

`establish_connection "db2_#{Rails.env}"`

I am using multi-database-migrations gem https://github.com/azitabh/multi-database-migrations and it works fine when I run

```
rake db:multi:migrate DATABASE=db2
```

At the moment my database.yml looks like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

db2_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

but I want it to look like this

```
db1_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:

db2_development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

My question is where should I tell rails to look for "db1_#{Rails.env}" ?

I was thinking to add something like this in my application.rb:

```
ENV['ENV'] ||= 'development'

db_conf = YAML::load(File.read("config/database.yml"))

DB1_CONF = db_conf["db1_#{Rails.env}"][ENV['ENV']]
DB2_CONF = db_conf["db2_#{Rails.env}"][ENV['ENV']]
```

but I'm not sure where I should call the constants DB1_CONF.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`development` is the environment the rails app is running in if started locally and is configured via the `database.yml` for this environment so your models will "fallback" to the default database configuration of `development`. If you want them connect to `db1_development` you will have to tell the models explicitly like you do with db2 established connections. If you dont follow the convention over configuration you have to be explicit. Or you might ask yourself why you dont want to stick to the conventions in the first place.